# URL rewrite a part of an url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change url's like this:

www.website.com/work/article

to:

www.website.com/article

Not for a single url, but for all pages with /work/ in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^work(/|$) /work%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```